# How to Automatically Use a DataTemplate Based on ContentControl's Current Content's DataType

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

When I attempt to specify multiple DataTemplates for use by a ContentControl so that the correct one (based on Type) is used, I end up with Content that is simply the Content's ToString() value.

```
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding MyTreeRootViewModels}" Content="{Binding /, Path=CurrentlySelectedTreeViewModel}">
  <ContentControl.Resources>
     <DataTemplate DataType="x:Type vm:TypeAViewModel">
        <StackPanel>
           <local:TypeAUserControl />
           </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>

     <DataTemplate DataType="x:Type vm:TypeBViewModel">
        <StackPanel>
           <local:TypeBUserControl />
        </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

In the example above I would see `MyApp.ViewModel.TypeAViewModel` displayed when a tree node of `TypeAViewModel` is returned by `CurrentlySelectedTreeViewModel`. I expect to see my `TypeAViewModelUserControl`.

I've tried putting a single `<TextBlock Text="TESTING"/>` element in one of my data templates just to see if the problem was related to my user controls. Same result.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

(By the way, the `CurrentlySelectedTreeViewModel` is a property that returns the currently selected node in my `TreeView`. It seems to work just fine - as I select nodes in the tree, the correct type name for the node appears `ContentControl`).

Comment: Trying to do the same thing; my problem was I didn't have my `DataTemplates` in the `ContentControl.Resources`.  Your example was my solution!  :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `x:Type` bit should be between curly braces `{}`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TypeAViewModel}">
```

Comment: Dooh. Thanks Bubblewrap.<MyFace BackgroundColor="Red" />

Answer (score 7):

`x:Type` is a *MarkupExtension*, which requires `{}` to indicate to the XAML compiler.