# WPF user control bind data to user control property

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, controls

I have user control:

xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="controlmaker.checkButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="114" d:DesignWidth="221">
<Grid Background="Aqua" >
    <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="58,24,0,0" Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Content="{Binding buttText}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="58,57,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

code behind

```
public partial class checkButton : UserControl
{
    public checkButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty buttTextProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("buttText", typeof(String),
typeof(checkButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public String buttText
    {
        get { return GetValue(buttTextProperty).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(buttTextProperty, value); }
    }


}
```

and main window xaml

```
<Window x:Class="controlmaker.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:controlmaker">
<Grid>
    <my:checkButton buttText="aka"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,115,0,0" x:Name="checkButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="133" Width="250" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to bind user control property in window xaml and bind it in user control to button content property. How to do it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can try Element binding inside the user control. Just give a name to UserControl and bind property:

```
<UserControl x:Class="controlmaker.checkButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="114" d:DesignWidth="221"
         x:Name="MyUserControl">
<Grid Background="Aqua" >
    <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="58,24,0,0" Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Content="{Binding Path=buttText, ElementName=MyUserControl}"
          Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="58,57,0,0" 
          Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And then you can Bind or put static text from user control usage place

```
<my:checkButton buttText="aka" />
```

or

```
  <my:checkButton buttText="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
```

Comment: Anybody more interested how to make it more correct, I highly recommand [link](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html)

Comment: how you specify what type of VM user control should consider as reference data? Imagine, that VM is not in the same namespace, etc

Comment: Question was - to bind user control property in its own xaml, current sample do not use MVVM pattern, if you need use MVVM and bind view model in user control then you have to set DataContext of user control to View Model instance or if you need type refenrencing consider DataTemplate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149117/how-to-automatically-use-a-datatemplate-based-on-contentcontrols-current-conten

Comment: @newman link is dead now, thanks anyway :)

Comment: The link mentioned in first comment seems to have changed to https://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html