# Button User Control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a user control library starting with buttons. I have managed to create a button.xaml with code as shown below;

```
<UserControl x:Class="SPECTRE.UserControls.Buttons.button"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SPECTRE.UserControls.Buttons"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
         x:Name="RootElement">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DangerButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F12427"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="Content" Value="Go"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="5">
                        <ContentPresenter
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        Margin="0,0,0,5"
                        Content="Button Text"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#D6E006"/>
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <!--Content should be dynamic-->
    <Button  Style="{StaticResource DangerButton}" Name="button1"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And I have a user control file video.xaml where the button is instantiated as below;

```
<Buttons:button/>
```

I am trying to make the button content dynamic but I can't seem to get it right. I tried this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461660/wpf-user-control-bind-data-to-user-control-property) but it couldn't work. What do I need to do?

Comment: Why are you creating a `UserControl` instead of simply creating a custom `Button`  style?

Comment: I was asked to create a UI library and so I am just exploring what is possible since I am new to WPF development. From your response and @mm8, it seems a button user control is not possible.

Comment: A custom `Button` control. Not a `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only custom thing you have defined there is the `Style`. Move the `Style` to `App.xaml` or another resource dictionary and then simply replace the `UserControl` with a `Button` element:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource DangerButton}" Name="button1" Content="Content..."/>
```

Another option may to to create a custom `DangerButton` control that inherits from `Button`:

```
public class DangerButton : Button
{
    static DangerButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DangerButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DangerButton)));
    }
}
```

In this case, you should define the default `Style` for the control in a resource dictionary named (by convention) `themes/generic.xaml`.

So move your current `Style` there and remove `x:Key="DangerButton"` from it. You can then use the custom control like this:

```
<Buttons:DangerButton Content="Content..." />
```

If you choose to simply wrap the `Button` in a `UserControl`, you won't be able to set any of the `Button`'s properties directly from the control where you consume the `UserControl`. You will then have to add properties to the `UserControl` and bind these to the `Button`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I think using styles will be a better option, creating custom controls creates a file Themes/Generics.xaml which when modified prevents one from creating any more custom controls and to avoid that I will use styles and user controls where possible.

Comment: Why would `hemes/Generics.xaml` "prevent one from creating any more custom controls"...? It doesn't. And wrapping a button in a user control is a bad idea.

Comment: If you make any change to it and try to create a custom control it gives an error and the created custom control won't be added to the file automatically as supposed to unless it is okay to add it manually there after.

Comment: Your response did the trick, all I had to do was keep the `Themes/Generics.xaml` file closed while creating another custom control. Thanks for the help.