# WPF ViewModel instantiation affecting child inheritance

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, datacontext

I have a child user control (Page1) which is failing to inherit the ViewModel (WizardPageViewModel) set on the DataContext of my WPF window when its declared inline in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFToolkitWizard.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:common="clr-namespace:WPFToolkitWizard"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <common:WizardPageViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <common:MyWizardControl>
        <common:MyWizardControl.Pages>
            <common:Page1 Title="Page 1" Description="First page" IsValid="true" />
        </common:MyWizardControl.Pages>
    </common:MyWizardControl>
</Grid>
```

However, if I change it as a static resource and reference it as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
<common:WizardPageViewModel x:Key="vm" />
</Window.Resources>

<common:Page1 Title="Page 1" Description="First page" IsValid="true" DataContext="{StaticResource vm}" />
```

The bindings declared in Page1 which are dependant upon the injected VM work ok.  The problem is I want to reference the ViewModel from the DataContext property of the Window as this is how we declare our VMs across the team:

```
<Window.DataContext>
<common:WizardPageViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

I have tried setting the bindings as follows, but no such luck:

```
<common:Page1 Title="Page 1" Description="First page" IsValid="true" DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

Also I have read post on SO that the DataContext is automatically inherited, but its not working in this circumstance.

Looking at the detailed debug output it is as follows:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=26218178): Default mode resolved to TwoWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=26218178): Default update trigger resolved to LostFocus
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=26218178): Attach to     System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.Text (hash=35377412)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=26218178): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=26218178): Found data context element: TextBox (hash=35377412) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=26218178): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=26218178): Resolve source deferred
```

It states DataContext is null, but I just don't know why its not automatically finding my VM instance.

MyWizardControl is a user control

Page1 is a ContentControl

Comment: I know you're trying to find a work around for it, but becareful using your VM as a static resource. All resources (static & dynamic) are shared instances, so anything else bound to that resource will be given the same instance as your Window in this example is given. If you can't get this to work, make sure and set [x:Shared](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx) to false.

Answer (score -1):

Seems working as expected for me.

From the structure of your code I assume that `common:MyWizardControl` is an `ItemsControl`, as it contains a `Pages` Property.

If that's true, then `ItemsControl` elements (in your case your page) inherit the ViewModel from the `ItemControl`'s  Source `ItemsSource` property, which would be an `ObservableCollection<WizardPageViewModel>` in your case.

Since you don't set the `ItemSource` property on the `ItemsControl`, it's empty, WPF can't assign any data context to it.

The static one works, because you set it explicitly, overriding any possible `DataContext` set by `ItemSource`.

That being said, you got three options:

1. Instantiate it statically and assign it yourself, as you did in your example (not very elegant)
2. Use an MVVM Framework with an ViewModelLocator (i.e. Microsofts Prism Framework), that would explicitly resolve the `View` each time the view is instantiated (either by code or from XAML)
3. Create a `MyWizardViewModel` which contains an `ObservableCollection<WizardPageViewModel> Pages {get;set;}` and bind it to `ItemsSource` of `WizardPageViewModel`.

First option feels a bit dirty, but may be fine for a demo or teaching project.

Second one works well for reusable Views/ViewModels and in case of Prims ViewModelLocator will create a new instance of the ViewModel for each `Page1` view you insert in your XAML. You can use a single instance of the ViewModel in multiple `Page1` controls if you use dependency injection framework (like Unity, MEF, Autofac etc.)

Third option is preferred one, as a ViewModel is meant to be used with a view and your `View` is the `Page1`, not the `MyWizardControl` (Actually `MyWizardControl` is a view on it's own with subviews, each of them meant to have it's own ViewModels representing the data that the View needs).

Third option is the easiest to implement, without having to work into a MVVM framework or dependency injection

**Edit: An example**

```
// Prism ViewModel base class, adjust for your framework or whatever you use as base
public class MyWizardViewModel : BindableBase 
{
    public ObservableCollection<WizardPageViewModel> Pages { get; set; }

    public MyWizardViewModel()
    {
        Pages = new ObservableCollection<WizardPageViewModel>()
        {
            new WizardPage1ViewModel(), // public class WizardPage1ViewModel : WizardPageViewModel
            new WizardPage2ViewModel() // public class WizardPage2ViewModel : WizardPageViewModel
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFToolkitWizard.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:common="clr-namespace:WPFToolkitWizard"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <common:WizardPageViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <common:MyWizardControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}" />
</Grid>
```

Then you just need to make DataTemplates for each ViewModel and then the ContenControl will display the correct template depending on the type of the DataContext. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149117/how-to-automatically-use-a-datatemplate-based-on-contentcontrols-current-conten)

Comment: He said `MyWizardControl` is a `UserControl`. Page1 is a ContentControl. He is basically adding a ContentControl to what appears to be a collection of them on the UserControl.

Comment: Also, if he does chose to just go the static resource route, he needs to make sure and set [x:Shared="false"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx). Otherwise that view model instance might be shared with other elements in the future, as WPF treats it as a singleton instance.

Comment: The `<common:MyWizardControl.Pages>` line makes no sense otherwise. It's plural form suggest, that it will be able to contain more than one view and just `ItemsControl` are meant for this. Either `MyWizardControl` or `Pages` is an `ItemsControl` or something that derives form it (`TabControl`, etc) otherwise you can't host multiple views in it. Whatever the case is, the fact still stands that it's related to `ItemsControl` and the way it manages DataContext of it's `ItemsSource` elements