# How to use DataTemplateSelector with ContentControl to display different controls based on the view-model?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplateselector

I want to create a simple window that would display different controls (`SpinEdit` or `TextEdit`) based on the view-model that is selected.

I have the code and logic behind it done already, what is left is displaying the control (`SpinEdit` or `TextEdit`) itself.

XAML:

```
   <dx:DXWindow.Resources>

      <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Value">
         <dxe:SpinEdit Height="23" MinWidth="200" Width="Auto"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       Mask="{Binding Mask, Mode=OneWay}" 
                       MaxLength="{Binding Path=InputLength}" />

      </DataTemplate>

      <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Text">
         <dxe:TextEdit Height="23" MinWidth="200" Width="Auto"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       MaskType="RegEx" Mask="{Binding Mask, Mode=OneWay}"
                       MaxLength="{Binding Path=InputLength}"/>
      </DataTemplate>

      <local:PropertyDataTemplateSelector  x:Key="templateSelector"
         DataTemplate_Value="{StaticResource DataTemplate_Value}"
         DataTemplate_Text="{StaticResource DataTemplate_Text}" />

   </dx:DXWindow.Resources>



  <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" >
         <Label x:Uid="Label" MinHeight="24" MinWidth="60" Content="Value" />
         <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
      </StackPanel>

      <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Uid="OKCancel_Buttons" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
         <Button Height="23" x:Name="OK_Button" Click="OK_Click" Content="OK" IsDefault="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="95" />
         <Button Height="23" x:Name="Cancel_Button" Click="Cancel_Click" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="95" />
      </StackPanel>
```

Where in the `<ContentControl>` I want to select which control will be displayed (`SpinEdit` for numbers and `TextEdit` for names/letters)

C#:

```
   public class PropertyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
   {
      public DataTemplate DataTemplate_Value { get; set; }
      public DataTemplate DataTemplate_Text { get; set; }

      public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
      {
         var selector = item as TInputBaseVM;

         if(selector is TInputValueVM)
            return DataTemplate_Value;
         return DataTemplate_Text;
      }
   }
```

Where I want to return a specific `DataTemplate` based on the view-model that is created in the c++/cli code.

C++/cli:

```
  TInputValueVM ^oExchange_Value;
  TInputTextVM ^oExchange_Text;

  int inputFormat = A_Attributes.GetInputFormat();

  if(inputFormat)
     oExchange_Text = gcnew TInputTextVM(gcnew System::String(A_Attributes.GetTitle()), gcnew System::String(A_Attributes.GetMask()),
        A_Attributes.GetInputLength(), gcnew System::String(A_Attributes.GetInitialText()));
  else
     oExchange_Value = gcnew TInputValueVM(gcnew System::String(A_Attributes.GetTitle()), gcnew System::String(A_Attributes.GetMask()),
        A_Attributes.GetInputLength(), A_Attributes.GetInitialValue());

  Dialogs::TSignalNumberPositionDialog^ dialog = gcnew Dialogs::TSignalNumberPositionDialog();

  if(inputFormat)
     dialog->DataContext = oExchange_Text;
  else
     dialog->DataContext = oExchange_Value;

  dialog->ShowDialog();
```

The point is, the `item` value in the overriden selector function always has the `null` value and I have no idea how to bind it in XAML since all the examples I've managed to find so far are `ListBox`es etc. There's no example on how to display different controls based on the view-model.

EDIT:

As suggested, I added Content property in the ContentControl and passed it an argument which is now the 'item' argument in the selector. Works just fine!

Comment: You need to set the `Content` of your `ContentControl`: `Content={Binding}`.

Comment: @dymanoid I did just that, I binded it to the string property that is being set in the constructor of each VM and I check that string in the Selector to return the correct VM but the 'item' argument still comes in as a null;

EDIT: I tried passing a string and not binding a property and it works that way, thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a DataTemplateSelector? Just set the DataType property of the DataTemplates, and they will be selected automatically when you set the Content of a ContentControl. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3149117/1136211

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a DataTemplateSelector. WPF provides a mechanism that automatically selects a DataTemplate for the ContentTemplate of a ContentControl according to the type of a Content.

As explained in [Data​Template.​Data​Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> When you set this property to the data type without specifying an x:Key, the DataTemplate gets applied automatically to data objects of that type.

So drop the `x:Key` value and your DataTemplateSelector, set DataType

```
<dx:DXWindow.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TInputValueVM}">
        <dxe:SpinEdit Height="23" MinWidth="200" Width="Auto"
                      Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Mask="{Binding Mask, Mode=OneWay}" 
                      MaxLength="{Binding Path=InputLength}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TInputTextVM}">
        <dxe:TextEdit Height="23" MinWidth="200" Width="Auto"
                      Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      MaskType="RegEx" Mask="{Binding Mask, Mode=OneWay}"
                      MaxLength="{Binding Path=InputLength}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</dx:DXWindow.Resources>
```

and bind the ContentControl's Content to a property that returns either a TInputValueVM or a TInputTextVM:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding InputVM}" />
```

The appropriate DataTemplate will now be selected automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some value in the `Content` property of the `ContentControl`. That value will be passed to the `SelectTemplate` as the `object item`. You probably should bind to it some property in your ViewModel to be able to change that from there.

Comment: Oh, i thought that the Content property had the same function as Text in my DataTemplates. I passed a string in the Content property and now it works just fine. Thanks!